# Store a pandas dataframe as an Excel object in S3 from AWS lambda using "Openpyxl"

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm writing a lambda function to read an S3 object (Excel) and write it back in S3 from the lambda function. Not able to use the writer function here as it's a read-only environment.

Was able to retrieve the object using Openpyxl, but not able to write it back in S3 again.

Forced to deploy and use "xlsxwriter" engine within lambda environment to write an object back into S3. Ideally, any one of the engines (either openpyxl or xlsxwriter) should be capable of doing both operations (read, write)

Here is the code, not sure what is wrong here.

```
#S3 Object Read code
obj                  =  S3_Client.get_object(Bucket="Bucket_Name", Key="Object_Key")
data                 =  obj['Body'].read()
AMR_Template         =  pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data), dtype = str, engine = "openpyxl")

#S3 Oject Write Code
with io.BytesIO() as output:
  with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    DF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Data", index = False)
    data = output.getvalue()
     
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('Bucket_Name').put_object(Key="Object Key", Body=data)
```

Comment: So what is your issue? You haven't specified any problem, error messages or a code sample.

Comment: I could read Excel S3 objects using Openpyxl only and write back an S3 object using "xlsxwriter" only. Ideally, both excel engines (openpyxl, xlsxwriter) should be capable of doing both operations (read, write).